# If this is proper Model-View-Controller, then why do I feel so dirty?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller

I have a Controller that responds to UI events from a View, setting the state of a Preference in the Model, and then calling other Controller code to change the content of the View.

The problem: in this case, the Model isn't informing the Controller that the Preference has changed -- the Controller is taking advantage of the fact that it knows it is the only one that can set that preference.

Put into concrete terms: a pull-down menu in the View is changed to reflect the kind of data that is displayed in a table in the View. The Model tracks the state of that menu preference, because this Model contains the business logic to generate the text used by the Controller to populate the View's table.

But there is no connection from the Model informing the Controller that the Model's representation of the Preference (pull-down menu choice) has changed; I've skipped that because the only way for that data in the Model to change is through a user-invoked action in the View -- which the Controller moderates.

Yet, the vast majority of my Model DOES send messages to interested Controllers when Model data changes, because in those cases, business logic can modify the Model.

Is this a violation of the MVC paradigm?

Is it impure to take advantage of the Controller's knowledge that it is the ONLY setter of this data in the Model?

Why do I feel like I am getting away with something that is just wrong?

Note: in this case, the Model is C++ and the Controller and View are Objective-C & Cocoa.

Comment: Haha, that title

Comment: Half the point of MVC is to divide responsibilities.  The other half is to make it easy to have many-one and many-many interactions.  Your solution makes multiple views of the same model not work.

Comment: @yakk -- sorry -- forgot to mention -- for this window/view -- there can only be one instance in the application.

Comment: @SMGreenfield If your application is never going to be refactored and never changed, anything that works is good.  If your application is ever going to be refactored or changed in any way, then a strong division of responsibilities and logically simple dependencies (ie, the details of the implication of one component not determining the correctness of another) is good.  Is it best?  Is your code completely throw-away?  Is speed of development worth making your code slipshod?  There are valid reasons to blur lines and take short cuts.